# swiftui Alignment Guide for two view

Tags: swiftui, alignment, swiftui-alignment-guide

I have two Rectangles, Rectangle A and Rectangle B. Rectangle A will move horizontally, and the center point of A will align with the top left corner of B in the horizontal direction. B will rotate around its own center point.

[image]

I have some code but I don't know how to writing next. How can I use `alignmentGuide` and `PreferenceKey` to achieve this animation?

```swift
struct MyAnchorKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Anchor<CGPoint>? = nil

    static func reduce(value: inout Anchor<CGPoint>?, nextValue: () -> Anchor<CGPoint>?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            // Rectangle A
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                // How to use alignmentGuide to align the center point with the top left corner of B
            // Rectangle B
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAngle))
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 3).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                // How to use anchorPreference to record top leading position
                
        }
        .onAppear {
            rotationAngle = 360
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: cleaned up*

The main complication here is that the displacement of Rectangle A is going to need to be computed from the rotation angle using trigonometry. This means, if you want it to be animated, you are going to need an `Animatable` view modifier to perform the computation.

There is also a problem with the width of the VStack stretching. When an alignment guide is used, the overall width of the VStack is going to change when Rectangle A is at the limits of its movement. This stretching of the width will have an impact on the position of Rectangle B too. However, this can be resolved quite easily by adding horizontal padding to Rectangle B, to allow space for the movement of Rectangle A.

This seems to work:

```swift
struct PositionModifier: ViewModifier, Animatable {

    let halfDiagonal: CGFloat
    let startAngle: CGFloat
    var rotationAngle: CGFloat

    init(sizeB: CGSize, rotationAngle: CGFloat) {
        let w = sizeB.width
        let h = sizeB.height
        self.halfDiagonal = sqrt((w * w) + (h * h)) / 2
        self.startAngle = atan(-w / h)
        self.rotationAngle = rotationAngle
    }

    /// Implementation of protocol property
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { rotationAngle }
        set { rotationAngle = newValue }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center, computeValue: { d in
            d.width / 2 -
            (halfDiagonal * sin((rotationAngle * Double.pi / 180) + startAngle))
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    private let sizeA = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    private let sizeB = CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 50) {
            // Rectangle A
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: sizeA.width, height: sizeA.height)
                .modifier(PositionModifier(sizeB: sizeB, rotationAngle: rotationAngle))

            // Rectangle B
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: sizeB.width, height: sizeB.height)
                .padding(.horizontal, sizeA.width / 2)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAngle))
        }
        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 3).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: rotationAngle)
        .onAppear {
            rotationAngle = 360
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative and perhaps simpler approach is to set an x-offset on Rectangle A, instead of using an alignment guide. Just change the body of the view modifier to the following:

```swift
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.offset(x:
            halfDiagonal * sin((rotationAngle * Double.pi / 180) + startAngle)
        )
    }
```

The padding on Rectangle B can be removed too.